# error: expected expression before ‘char’

Tags: c, function, for-loop, if-statement, ansi-c

Excuse me , I have a problem when I compile my code, and i don't don't how to solve it because I don't know what it ask for.

This appears me in the terminal:

**" usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In the functión `_start':
/build/buildd/glibc-2.21/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:114: reference to`main' without define
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 "**

I leave my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void calcular_vocal(char cadena[]){
   int l;
   char vocales[5]="a,e,i,o,u";
   int i, vector contadores[5];
   l=strlen(cadena);
   for(i=0;i<l;i++){
     if(cadena[i] =='a')
        cadena a++;
        vector contadores[0]++;
     if(cadena[i] =='e')
        cadena e++;
        vector contadores[1]++;;
     if(cadena[i] == 'i')
        cadena i++;
        vector contadores[2]++;
     if(cadena[i] =='o')
        cadena o++;
        vector contadores[3]++;
     if(cadena[i] =='u')
        cadena u++;
        vector contadores[4]++;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
      int max,pos;
      if(vector contadores[i]>max){
         max = vector contadores [i];
         pos = i;
      }
    }
     printf("The most repeated vocal is %c %d",vocales[pos],max);
   }
}
int main (void){
   char calcular_vocal(char[]);
}
```

Comment: no, this is the problem XD

Comment: But this is actually the code you've run through the compiler? Because it seems as though you're getting a linker error while the compiler shouldn't really compile your code:
int i, vector contadores[5];

is illegal. What would vector be?

You also don't initialize your ints anywhere so you're bound to get garbage values in there.
a, e, o and u also appear to not be declared. You have declared i, however it's intended as the counter for your loop.

Comment: So, in conclution, I should declare the a e i o u variables, and declare the vector separate from the i variable?

Comment: And , what happens respect from the main function ??

Comment: You should initialize variables to 0. If you need i you should change your other i's name. You don't really need that vector, whatever it's supposed to be (C, unlike C++, doesn't have a vector type in the standard library).

Comment: `vector contadores[5];` - this bit does not make any sense

Comment: It's that I do not understand what you said, really XD

Comment: what is the `vector` in your code? The only way I could imagine this to work would be to have some preprocessor symbol that refers to nothing or to strange things...

Comment: "vector" is the name I give to the variable, which ironically is also a vector XD

Comment: A variable name can't contain a space.

Comment: This code can be compilable only if it was written by using weirdest macros with purpose to surprise fellow developers. You don't have understanding even of language basics, such as how to use arrays, strings or how to call functions. Start learning C by reading Kernighan&Ritchie or similar book.

Comment: I know it , I'm starting computer engineering this year , and I'm still learning how to use it XD

Comment: Please add the exact compiler command that you used to get this output.

Comment: @gudok I don't think there is any possible macro which would make this code compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

It seems you are compiling the wrong file. See the following console commands and output (its german, but I think the message is sufficiently similar to yours):

```
$ rm test1.c 
$ touch test1.c
$ gcc test1.c 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In Funktion `_start':
(.text+0x20): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$
```

Long story short: you compile the wrong file (probably an empty one) and for that reason you get this error message which is totally unrelated to any of your code.

---

**Original Answer**

I'm going to assume a few things about your code, in order to provide you an answer that results in a compilable code - whether the result of running the program means anything is up to you (to be honest, I intentionally suggest changes that won't give you the program you most probably want, since you need something to learn with).

I start with your main function

```
int main (void){
   char calcular_vocal(char[]);
}
```

What you do inside the main function, is writing a declaration of the `calcular_vocal` function, but with a different function signature than your actual implementation. Change it to `void calcular_vocal(char[]);` in order to have this part compilable.

Now to the code inside the `calcular_vocal` function:

The line `char vocales[5]="a,e,i,o,u";` is not allowed, because the string size is to big for your array. Increase the array size to 9 or 10 in order to have enough space available: `char vocales[9] = "a,e,i,o,u";`

Moving on to line `int i, vector contadores[5];`, assuming you want to have a variable named "vector contadores". You cannot have space in your variable names, so rename it to "vector_contadores" for all occurences in order to make this piece work.

Moving on to all the if-statements. They are all the same, so I only write something about the first one. The code `cadena a++;` is invalid. You have multiple options to solve this. (1) erase the `a` from that code (`cadena++;`). (2) define integer variable for `a` and remove `cadena` from the code (`a++;`). (3) rewrite to `cadena['a']++;`. There are even more options to make this part compileable.

The variables `int max,pos;` are defined inside the for-loop but are used outside. Move their definition to the top of the function, where you define your other variables. Also, initialize `max` with value `-1`.

This should be all you need to compile this piece of code (unless I forgot something)

Comment: _for_ `"a,e,i,o,u"` ...  _Increase the array size to 9 or 10_.  What is it, 9 or 10?  The way you have it (  `vocales[9] = "a,e,i,o,u"` )  is wrong because there will be no room for the NULL character.  A safe option is to suggest: `char vocales[]="a,e,i,o,u";`.  This ensures the proper initialization will occur.  (which will be 10 bytes).

Comment: @ryyker Ok, I could re-phrase it to only mentioning size 9, since this is the minimum needed. I also mentioned 10, because this is the actual string size including the terminating zero. I did not mention, that any size larger than 9 is also valid (not only 10). I dislike the idea to ommit the size, since for me this would imply a size-sensitive usage, which is not the case (not very rational, i know). I'll think about it a bit before editing ;)

Comment: _...size 9, since this is the minimum needed..._  No, the string; `"a,e,i,o,u"` requires a minimum of 10 bytes to be a string.  A C string requires the null terminator.  It is not an option.  In memory this string looks like: `|a|,|e|,|i|,|o|,|u|\0|`. and requires in 10 characters.

Comment: @ryyker You are the only one talking about strings here... the use case is an array initializer and there the compiler gracefully allows using strings at all (where it should be a char array) and it allows to initialize the char array members to correspond to the string content without the trailing zero. So what you suggest is about style, not about compilability. And my answer is most certainly NOT about style.

Comment: I am not the only one talking about strings.  You brought it up.  From your own answer: _The line char vocales[5]="a,e,i,o,u"; is not allowed, because the_ ***string*** size is...   If you do not want to use the information, just ignore it.

Comment: sorry @grek40 but I changed the function inside the main function to **void calcular_vocal(char[]);** , as you told me , and still does not compile.

Comment: @V_WraMphT3R You have to be a bit more specific here... did you apply ALL changes as suggested? What is your error message?

Comment: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In the `_start' function:
/build/buildd/glibc-2.21/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:114: reference  to `main' without define
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @V_WraMphT3R Before we continue... did you successfully compile other programs before?

Comment: @grek40 if with "compiling", you mean to compiling a program without errors, yes XD

Comment: @V_WraMphT3R See my update for the error message that you actually get... totally unrelated to your code ;)

Comment: @grek40 forgiveness, but now I get it, that sure is a silly mistake, but I do not understand:

Comment: file1.c:17:17: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘e’
          cadena e++;
                 ^
file1.c:20:17: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘i’
          cadena i++;
                 ^
file1.c:23:17: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘o’
          cadena o++;
                 ^
file1.c:26:17: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘u’
          cadena u++;
                 ^
file1.c: In function ‘main’:
file1.c:39:4: error: too many arguments to function ‘calcular_vocal’
    calcular_vocal(caracteres,N);
    ^
file1.c:4:5: note: declared here
 int calcular_vocal(char cadena[N]){

Comment: @V_WraMphT3R please understand that the comment section of stackoverflow is no substitute for your basic understanding of programming languages. Re-read my post and understand, that the things I wrote about `cadena a++;` apply to ALL of these code lines, no matter whethere there is an `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` or `u`

Comment: @grek40 One last thing, in the terminal I still appears me  things in the code that I delete long ago, for example, I modify *** int calcular_vocal (char string []) {*** to *** void calcular_vocal (char string []) {*** and I still appears me on the terminal when I  compile  *** int calcular_vocal (char string []) {***, why is that?